# Google Map v3 - MarkerWithLabel. Label dont exist in IE9

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I'm porting Google Map from v2 api to v3. Of course I encountered a problem. I use MarkerWithLabel() to create markers with title. In every browsers (even in IE8) except IE9 labels are visible. Where could be a problem?

[image]

This is my code of marker with laber builder function:

```
function createRegionMarker(pointData) {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(pointData.lat, pointData.lng);
    var image = new google.maps.MarkerImage("/images/rall.png", new google.maps.Size(40, 40), new google.maps.Point(0,0), new google.maps.Point(0, 32));

var marker = new MarkerWithLabel({
    position: latlng,
    icon: image,
    clickable: true,        
    draggable: false,
    map: map,
    labelContent: pointData.id,
    labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(-10, 20),
    labelClass: "map-labels",
    labelInBackground: false
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
        zoomMarker(pointData.lng, pointData.lat, 8);
});

return marker;
}
```

Comment: I updated MarkerWithLabel class and now works like a charm. http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerwithlabel/1.1.4/src/markerwithlabel.js

Comment: What do you mean by "labels are not visible in IE"? I'm having the exact same problem, but I want to know how it manifests on other projects.

Comment: If I remember well, labels was covered by background. After updating the script works well.

Comment: My problem was that IE couldn't parse commas after the last item in a list. For example, `labelInBackGround: false, });`. Notice the comma. Maybe it will help someone else.

Comment: Always when you're creating/initializing javascript object/array there shouldn't be a comma after last item at all.